# Unable to mount read an write partitions

Tags: mount, fstab, ntfs-3g

I use for a half and a year Linux with 6 HDD with NTFS format and modify my fstab to can read and write, also I have ntfs-3g installed.

```
    UUID=480a3f32-e304-49b0-b322-4964349fd941       /               ext4            rw,relatime,data=ordered        0 1
UUID=BAF0D1D3F0D195CB /media/ntfs/Anime ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000,umask=022 0 0
UUID=561CAEE01CAEB9FF /media/ntfs/Anime2.0 ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000,umask=022 0 0
UUID=68B283CAB2839AE8 /media/ntfs/Anime3.0 ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000,umask=022 0 0
UUID=E094004194001CA2 /media/ntfs/Anime4.0 ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000,umask=022 0 0
UUID=CAE8F43AE8F425FB /media/ntfs/Anime5.0 ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000,gid=users,umask=022 0 0
UUID=8A34984034983165 /media/ntfs/Anime6.0 ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000,gid=users,umask=022 0 0
UUID=64E6CDCBE6CD9E24 /media/ntfs/Win ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000,umask=022 0 0
UUID=AADEEA03DEE9C7A1 /media/ntfs/KK ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000,umask=022 0 0
```

Today I can't write or modify the HDD on the fstab with ntfs-3g, the mount command return the following info:

```
    proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
dev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8173120k,nr_inodes=2043280,mode=755)
run on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755)
/dev/sdh1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=35,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdh3 on /media/ntfs/Win type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdb2 on /media/ntfs/Anime2.0 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdc2 on /media/ntfs/Anime6.0 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sde2 on /media/ntfs/Anime5.0 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda1 on /media/ntfs/Anime3.0 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdd2 on /media/ntfs/KK type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdg2 on /media/ntfs/Anime type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdf2 on /media/ntfs/Anime4.0 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1642420k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=985)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=985)
```

As you can see the ntfs-3g partitons are mounted as ro instead rw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

man ntfs-3g

```
   Windows hibernation and fast restarting
       On  computers  which  can be dual-booted into Windows or Linux, Windows
       has to be fully shut down before booting into Linux, otherwise the NTFS
       file systems on internal disks may be left in an inconsistent state and
       changes made by Linux may be ignored by Windows.

       So, Windows may not be left in hibernation when starting Linux, in  or‐
       der to avoid inconsistencies. Moreover, the fast restart feature avail‐
       able on recent Windows systems has to be disabled. This can be achieved
       by  issuing as an Administrator the Windows command which disables both
       hibernation and fast restarting :

              powercfg /h off

       If either Windows is hibernated or its fast restart is enabled,  parti‐
       tions on internal disks are forced to be mounted in read-only mode.
```